# in-app subscription downgrade not working android

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I am developing an android app which has an in-app subscription(monthly and yearly)

1. A single subscription(both) are working as expected
2. 1st I am purchasing monthly and upgrade to yearly it is working as expected
3. 1st I am purchasing yearly and tried to downgrade and purchase monthly it is not working as expected and backend server receives a call back with the cancel status stated "System Cancel"

I am using `ProrationMode.DEFERRED` mode

Here is my upgrade code:

```
BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setOldSku(monthly_test)
                        .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED)
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsYearly)
                        .build();

 BillingResult responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(Activity.this, flowParams);
```

Here is downgrade code:

```
 BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setOldSku(Constants.yearly_test)
                        .setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED)
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsMonthly)
                        .build();

 BillingResult responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(Activity.this, flowParams);
```

Is there any other way to handle downgrade subscription?

Comment: Hi, did you make any progress on this? I am having the same issue where when downgrading the purchase details are not returned and after the current subscription expires acknowledging the purchase doesn't work

Comment: @Seeker, "DEFERRED" was not working for me. So, I started using "IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION" and it was working as expected. you can refer this link for all other modes: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode

Answer (score 0):

The implementation looks correct.

You can file bug to the development team by using their public issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=311487&template=1014446
The development team can provide more specific information through that channel.

Comment: Hi DrPower, can we use different proration modes in upgrade and downgrade?